# UIStackView inside a UITableViewCell does not adjust correctly on AutoLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uistackview

I have a UIStackView inside my UITableViewCell, which is displaying 6 views (3 labels, 3 textfields). The problem is that it does not display nicely when on iPhone SE.

[image: properties of stackview]

[image: My cell]
The De... textfield was supposed to be Depto.
The # textfield shouldnt be so wide.
[image: Preview]

The header of the table is also a StackView.
Any suggestion on how to make it work using AutoLayout?

Comment: What exactly is not displaying "nicely"?

Comment: The headers should be align with the fields on the cell. And the last label is not displaying entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to distribute your data proportionally in stack view. Stackview will proportionally distribute space for your conrols.[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the stack views aren't matching up the way you want, after setting the fill to `fill proportionally`, you can give each label/value pair the same proportional width, where the total widths equal 1 (i.e. 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2)